# How do I exclude my own window without flicker when I take a screenshot?

Tags: delphi, gdi, flicker, screen-capture

We have a Delphi-based application that captures the desktop via the GDI. The only problem is that the application window is being captured during the process as well, which we want to avoid.

We tried to resolve it by hiding and showing the application window before and after the capture operation, however this results in a heavy flickering.

Will appreciate any other methods suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: May be the moving app window outside the desktop area (e.g. `Left := 10000; Top := 10000;`) instead of hiding/showing will help.

Comment: You want to capture the desktop **excluding** the delphi application windows, but **including** all other shown ?

Comment: Pretty hard to see any other way to do this other than hiding your app. Windows won't paint what's beneath your app until you move it out of the way.

Comment: @PeterKostov indeed, we need the whole desktop except the app panel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How it possible then to time it with screen refreshes, in order to eliminate the flickering.

Comment: I doubt that it is. Which program do you know that does this? Are you wanting a single shot or a video?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Only on Windows XP and older does windows only render the visible portions of Windows. But on Windows Vista and newer with AERO desktop enabled windows actually repaints whole windows even when they are hidden by other windows. This alows you to see full preview of any application and also alows glas frame to work

Comment: @SilverWarior OP has not indicated that they do not care about XP support...

Comment: @silver they are only repainted when needed. So if no aero preview needed, no repaint for windows underneath others.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Wanna bet? On Aero desktop application windows are repainted whenever application requests repainting even if they are not seen (behind some other windows) or moved compleetly out of screen viewing area. The only time they are not repainted is when they are minimized. Don't belive me? Test it yourself. Create a new VCL application and put a button on it. In the buttons method put a for loop which will update froms Caption about 10k times. You will notice theat during the execution of that loop whole windows GUI starts to lag as hell. It continues...

Comment: ... Now change that code so that you hide your application window either by moving it off screen or placing behind some other window before the loop executes. You will se that windows GUI will still lag for the duration of loop execution. The reason why windows GUI starts to lagg so much in this scenario is becouse you are rapidly changing the window caption which requires your window border which is a glass frame to be compleetly repainted. And this repainting is slow and done in the thread from windows Aero. That is why everything starts to lagg. That is a major drawback of Aero GUI.

Comment: @Silver I'm talking about `WM_PAINT`, `InvalidateRect` etc. Not forced updates on a timer.

Comment: Who sad anything about the timer. All you do in example I propose is simply change the Forms Caption text. And changing the caption text requires for window frame to be repainted. And on Aero that happens if the window is seen or not which is my point. I strongly recomend you read some material about Aero desktop composition and how ti works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may resolve this using windows magnifier functionality. You can exclude or include any windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
So you can get a screen shot of the screen excluding the windows you do not need.
This approach will work on Windows upper then XP (7, vista, 8);

Comment: Thanks, was exactly what I've looked for!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna take a screenshot of the entire desktop and without your application window I belive there are two options.

1. As you already figured out you should hide the your applications window before taking a screenshot. Now minimizing and maximizing your application is not good due to minimization/maximization effects. So you can either try to move it out of visible area or maybe enable alpha transparency and temporary set it to 0 (fully transparent).
2. Another approach is to enumerate all visible windows, take screenshot of every specific window and then compose the final screenshot by placing combining screenshots of seperate windows by placing them in correct position. Now main advantage of such approach is that you can exclude whichever window you want, can even be a window of some other application which you don't have controll of. But the main disadvantage of such approach is that it is much slower and much more memory demanding.